# How do I change the default lock screen browser back to Windows Edge

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen

I recently clicked a link on my Windows 10 lock screen that I was interested in.  When the screen unlocked it asked if I wanted to use a different application to open this type of file.  It defaults to Microsoft Edge, which I am not a big fan of so I picked a different default.

The problem is that the link did not open properly in the new default browser and whenever I try to open a link from the lock screen it brings me to the default browser which fails to open the page I requested.  I have searched all over the Internet and was unable to find a good solution, even though some people had methods of resetting the lock screen that were not appealing.  Anyway to get this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out.  It was kind of what I was expecting, but I couldn't figure out how to change default app settings in Windows 10 for some reason.

1. From the Windows Start, search for "default app settings"
2. In the "Default apps" screen that appears, scroll to the bottom to find the "Set defaults by app" link
3. Find Microsoft Edge on the left side panel
4. Click the "Choose defaults for this program" link on the bottom of the main pane.
5. In the "Protocols" section, look for "MICROSOFT-EDGE" (Description "URL:microsoft-edge"). *In my case this was the other browser.*
6. Click the checkbox next to "MICROSOFT-EDGE" and Save.
7. The links on the lock screen now open in Edge successfully.

It would be nice if they opened in the other browser, but I was able to fix this annoyance.

Answer (score -1):

you could install edgedeflector

https://github.com/da2x/EdgeDeflector/releases

which redirects the url to the default webbrowser

Comment: That application does the opposite from what the OP asked (redirect Cortana searches, etc to another browser other than Edge) And, whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @CaldeiraG .. what he actually wanted to do primarily was to use another browser - most likely his default one .. the answer by itself wasn't completely off topic in that way .. about the essential parts - well the installer itself allows/opens the dialog to change the default - the reason why i didn't write more ..