# How can I open Windows Spotlight links in a browser other than Edge?

Tags: windows, browser, links, spotlight

I wonder, now that Edge chromium has been released it would be lovely to have links open in there other than in the old Edge. But I can't find out how it works. Is there a special protocol that handles lockscreen links? Is there a registry key to change? and so.

Comment: Try this :https://github.com/sylveon/SearchWithMyBrowser

Comment: This is just the opposite of what you want so take hints :https://superuser.com/questions/1313903/how-do-i-change-the-default-lock-screen-browser-back-to-windows-edge

Comment: Excellent! That worked. Thank you
Is there a way to mark your answer as helpful? I'm new to su.

Comment: Since there is no direct answer I will suggest you to answer your own question and Mark it as accepted :Refer here - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/how-do-i-upvote-or-downvote-comments

Comment: Actually I was trying to mark your answers as helpful ( i think helps in the reputation system) but if you don't mind then I'll do as you suggest

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. These links are hard coded to open in the Edge browser.

Good news is that when Edge Chromium replaces the current Edge, these links should then open in the new browser.